# VSTS SonarQube endpoint fails depending on the user who created it

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

We use [SonarQube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SonarQube) analysis in our [Azure DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps_Server) build pipelines. For some users, when they create the SonarQube Endpoint, the build pipeline works perfectly. For others, when they create it, with the same URL and token, the SonarQube prepare step fails with a *403 Forbidden error*.

I tried with the local SonarQube scanner and used the same token and URL successfully.

The only difference between successful and unsuccessful builds is the user who created the Service Connection in Azure DevOps.

What can we do to solve this strange situation?

Comment: Looks like you have an environment with different user roles. The security settings in Azure Devops are not always so obvious. An admin can create an endpoint and after adjusting the security of that endpoint every user can see and use that endpoint in the dropdown when creating a new build.So no need to create a new one. The Token you use must point to an user that has enough rights to execute an analysis. If you use HTTPS, be sure all build agents have initialized the Java keystore correctly.

Comment: The issue has been fixed by Microsoft in the meantime. See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/553500/sonarqube-endpoint-fails-depending-on-the-user-who.html